# Unity Get the actual rendered sprite height in Image UI

Tags: image, unity-game-engine, height, sprite

I have an Image on UI, and the "Preserve Aspect Ratio" for its sprite is True, so depending of the sprite attached to the image, the sprite may not cover all the rect of the Image, what i want is to get the real height of the rendered sprite so i can apply it to the rect Transform height of the Image and make them to has the same height

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution, remember that this works with "preserve aspect" allowed on the Image component. this function get the desired heigth, according to the width specified and the size of the texture of the sprite on the image.

```
/// <summary>
/// Get the height of an image according to the rendered sprite and the desired width(if is not specified, it will take the width of the own image's recTransform)
/// </summary>
public static float GetDesiredHeigth(this Image img, float desiredWidth = default)
{
    RectTransform ImageRect = img.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
    float _bodyWidth = desiredWidth == default ? ImageRect.rect.width : desiredWidth;
    float _imageWidth = (float)img.sprite.texture.width;
    float _imageHeight = (float)img.sprite.texture.height;
    float _ratio = _imageWidth / _imageHeight;
    float _expectedHeight = _bodyWidth / _ratio;
    return _expectedHeight;
}
```

So you can use it like this:

```
public Image image;

private void AdjustImageSizeToTextureRendered()
{
    float desiredHeigth = image.GetDesiredHeigth();
    image.rectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(image.rectTransform.sizeDelta.x, desiredHeigth);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get sprite height in pixels using `rect` field - that returns `Location of the Sprite on the original Texture, specified in pixels.` That means it would work for SpriteAtlas as well.

```
Vector2 size = myImage.sprite.rect.size;
//or
float width = myImage.sprite.rect.width;
float height = myImage.sprite.rect.height;
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment!, I have already tried it but it returns to me the same height that the current image has :c